# I bought a PS Vita used, help me get the old PSN account off

Tags: psn, ps-vita, playstation-plus

So everywhere says to go to system settings and just restore back to factory settings, but it doesn't let me get to that point because of the old users account on the Vita. I don't have the guys info to get ahold of and have him take it off and it doesnt let me enter mine because his is on there.. Help me get back to factory settings or enter my account and delete his. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a link on Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/playstation-nation-1000002/deactivate-second-hand-ps-vita-password-unkown-29225829/) to help you accomplish what you want. I've included the important text below.

> Power off the system and hold down the power button, right trigger, and playstation button at the same time and then a list of options will pop up. You can choose to restore the PS Vita, and format the memory card.

There is another comment a few down from this one that confirms this and was apparently what Sony support told them to do.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is how I did it:

Reboot to safemode > rebuilt database = did not work
Reboot in safemode > format memory cared = did not work
Reboot in safemode > restore system/format (*1)

*1 special note - it popped up to format the memory card associated with the old account = some as much as 3817 etc

It took my credentials without resetting the pw/acct etc.  It probably is a caching issue is my guess.